# Create a mysql replication from multiple master and single slave server?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication

How to create mysql replication with multiple master server and with single slave server? how to edit the "CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='12.34.56.789',MASTER_USER='slave_user', MASTER_PASSWORD='password', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS=  107;
" command to channelise different master db at the same time.

Comment: @Akina I have used Innodb engine to create the schemas .

Comment: No-no. You will use mysql_multi to create separate "virtual" slaves attached to slave databases using federated.

Comment: What version?  Only newer versions allow multiple masters to talk to one Slave, if that is what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the master and relay repositories to be stored into tables and then define channels for each master.

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL master_info_repository = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL relay_log_info_repository = 'TABLE';

CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='master1', MASTER_USER='rpl', MASTER_PORT=3451, MASTER_PASSWORD='' \
MASTER_LOG_FILE='master1-bin.000006', MASTER_LOG_POS=628 FOR CHANNEL 'master-1';
```

Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html